# Can I assign the sample rate or bit rate of m4a which was exported by AVAssetExportSession

Tags: iphone, ios, avfoundation

That is some code seg:

```
AVURLAsset *songAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:assetURL options:nil];
AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc]
                                      initWithAsset: songAsset
                                      presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A];
NSLog (@"created exporter. supportedFileTypes: %@", exporter.supportedFileTypes);
exporter.outputFileType = @"com.apple.m4a-audio";
[exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{}.....
```

I used this to export m4a from ipod library.

The size of this m4a file is 10M.

Can I compress the m4a through setting the sample rate of bit rate?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Daemon, did you managed to assign a sample / bit rate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot specify that directly. Your only options are:

```
NSString *const AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality;
NSString *const AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality;
NSString *const AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality;
```

Comment: this is used for video, not audio.